# Увелечения css как в бразурах

Tags: html, css, css3

Как реализовать в коде css такое же увелечение как у браузеров? Есть линия красная на 100% увелечение  она выглядит одним образом,когда в браузере увеличиваю на 500% она становится жирная,как реализовать вот это увелечения в коде может можно прописать чтобы сразу этот участок кода увеличивался на 500%?

transform:scale(2); не совсем подходит так как он увеличивает во всю длину

```css
#circle {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  /* Цвет линии */
  color: red;
  /* Цвет линии для IE6-7 */
  height: 2px;
  /* Толщина линии */
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var scale = 1;

circle.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  if (delta > 0) {
    scale += 0.05;
  } else {
    scale -= 0.05;
  }

  circle.style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
  /* Цвет линии */
  color: red;
  /* Цвет линии для IE6-7 */
  height: 25px;
  /* Толщина линии */
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Если прокрутить колёсиком над линией, она масштабируется... если я правильно понял чего вы хотите...

Answer (score 0):

> `transform:scale(2);` не совсем подходит так как он увеличивает во всю длину

```
transform: scaleY(2);
```